# How to change a flexbox item margin's color on hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive navbar where each item gets its' background highlighted (color change to higher saturation) on hover. However, [only the link text gets highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0vNB.png)

I'm using a flexbox container with evenly distribution, plus a logo with margin-right:auto so it stays fixed at the left side.

What I want is getting the whole space ([as seen in the dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z2Oj.png)
) highlighted on hover. After digging around, I believe that area highlighted using the dev-console is the margin, thus the question title.

I figured it out using padding but it looks sketchy, it jumps around so it's far from ideal.

Here's my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-nav {
  background-color: rgb(148, 174, 186);
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-links {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: wavy; //don't mind this, just how I managed to clear the links default styling
  height: auto;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  background: rgb(39, 136, 180);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <a class="logo-link" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src=img/Logotipo.png> </img>
  </a>
  <a class="nav-links" href=m y-bio.html>MY BIO</a>
  <a class="nav-links" href=e xperience.html>EXPERIENCE</a>
  <a class="nav-links" href=projects.html>PROJECTS</a>
  <a class="nav-links" href=hire-me.html>HIRE ME!</a>
</div>
```

I was thinking about making the links into divs but I'm afraid it will end up with the same result.

Comment: What's sketchy? I just replaced `margin` with `padding` and it works: https://nimb.ws/ftR1n4

Comment: Hey there, thanks for editing my question. 

So I tried to add padding on hover only. Like padding: 30px. 

Problems with that approach: I'm using a random value, not something fixed. It doesn't highlight everything right and left.

Problems with replacing margin with padding like how I think you did: 

The logo no longer stays fixed at the leftmost region. The background color only changes vertically? Horizontally is limited. 

See: https://i.imgur.com/8TSdzsl.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a background colour to a margin value, that isn't possible. If you want it to be in the links add the following to your `.nav-links` class:

```
.nav-links {
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

If you want the menu items to fill the full height of the parent element with the same effect you can do:

```
.nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

I'm not quite sure I know what you wish to achieve though.

Comment: @Lexxidon what space isn't highlighted? I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Hey sorry, that was before I saw your edit. With your edit, it works great! 

I just had to do a few tweaks: justify-content: center for the link text, and width:100% so the entire "horizontal space" between a link and the other is highlighted on hover. 

So it turned out that the solution was making the links into containers! I didn't expect that. 

Thanks a lot :)